# unable to create Travel label?

Tags: gmail

I have two gmail.com addresses. One of them has a "Travel" label but the other one does not and I can't create one without getting this error:

> Sorry, you can't create a label named "travel" (it's a reserved system label)

I don't understand. One of them already has a "Travel" label so why would it be an issue for the other one?

Comment: Shouldn't you ask your system administrator this question?

Comment: @User24601 - so I have two gmail.com addresses. One I use for personal stuff (like money stuff, etc) and the other I use for open source stuff. Like I have neubert@gmail.com, which I give to people I don't know who need help with my lib, and I have personalnickname@gmail.com, which IRL friends and family have. So both addresses are gmail.com accounts. My "personal" gmail account lets me create a "Travel" label but my neubert@gmail.com one does not. ie. they both have the same sys admins...

Comment: I see now that you have changed your question to make the issue more clear.